# Get the message from the array with most likes

Tags: php, arrays, facebook-graph-api, multidimensional-array

I'm having problem which I've not yet been able to solve.
I have this array and i am trying to print the most liked message and the number of likes

```
[data] => Array (
[0] => Array (
    [message] => Hello
    [created_time] => 2015-12-20T10:46:23+0000
    [id] => 730004193797310_729651713832558
    [likes] => Array (
        [data] => Array (
            [0] => Array (
                [id] => 730004193797310
                )
            )
        [paging] => Array (
            [cursors] => Array (
                [after] => NzMwMDA0MTkzNzk3MzEw
                [before] => NzMwMDA0MTkzNzk3MzEw
                )
            )
        )
    [comments] => Array (
        [data] => Array (
            [0] => Array (
                [comment_count] => 0
                [id] => 729651713832558_729706407160422
                )
            )
        [paging] => Array (
            [cursors] => Array (
                [after] => WTI5dGJXVnVkRjlqZFhKemIzSTZOekk1TnpBMk5EQTNNVFl3TkRJeU9qRTBOVEEyTVRVek9UUT0=
                [before] => WTI5dGJXVnVkRjlqZFhKemIzSTZOekk1TnpBMk5EQTNNVFl3TkRJeU9qRTBOVEEyTVRVek9UUT0=
                )
            )
        )
    )
[1] => Array (
    [created_time] => 2015-11-16T13:50:46+0000
    [id] => 730004193797310_718306454967084
    [likes] => Array (
        [data] => Array (
            [0] => Array (
                [id] => 1720104271557526
                )
            )
        [paging] => Array (
            [cursors] => Array (
                [after] => MTcyMDEwNDI3MTU1NzUyNg==
                [before] => MTcyMDEwNDI3MTU1NzUyNg==
                )
            )
        )
    )
[2] => Array (
    [created_time] => 2015-09-14T09:25:16+0000
    [id] => 1003599186377393_698778006919929
    )
[3] => Array (
    [created_time] => 2015-08-10T03:41:44+0000
    [id] => 1720104271557526_682359695228427
    )
[4] => Array (
    [created_time] => 2015-06-20T11:14:28+0000
    [id] => 993332777396253_661715567292840
    )
[5] => Array (
    [created_time] => 2015-02-12T19:58:43+0000
    [id] => 1162874437075962_604794729651591
    )
[6] => Array (
    [message] => Watching mukundha movie
    [created_time] => 2014-12-24T17:10:57+0000
    [id] => 1003599186377393_580507298747001
    )
[7] => Array (
    [created_time] => 2014-09-28T17:52:59+0000
    [id] => 730004193797310_542049265926138
    [likes] => Array (
        [data] => Array (
            [0] => Array (
                [id] => 730004193797310
                )
            )
        [paging] => Array (
            [cursors] => Array (
                [after] => NzMwMDA0MTkzNzk3MzEw
                [before] => NzMwMDA0MTkzNzk3MzEw
                )
            )
        )
    )
[8] => Array (
    [created_time] => 2014-09-26T13:51:10+0000
    [id] => 730004193797310_541135166017548
    [likes] => Array (
        [data] => Array (
            [0] => Array (
                [id] => 1162874437075962
                )
            )
        [paging] => Array (
            [cursors] => Array (
                [after] => MTE2Mjg3NDQzNzA3NTk2Mg==
                [before] => MTE2Mjg3NDQzNzA3NTk2Mg==
                )
            )
        )
    )
[9] => Array (
    [message] => watchìng Rabhasa
    [shares] => Array (
        [count] => 1
        )
    [created_time] => 2014-08-29T15:44:47+0000
    [id] => 1003599186377393_523096671154731
    )
[10] => Array (
    [shares] => Array (
        [count] => 1
        )
    [created_time] => 2014-08-26T11:01:54+0000
    [id] => 1003599186377393_521348074662924
    )
[11] => Array (
    [message] => Wish Facebook introduce an unlike button soon!!!!
    [created_time] => 2014-08-25T09:08:35+0000
    [id] => 730004193797310_520677651396633
    [likes] => Array (
        [data] => Array (
            [0] => Array (
                [id] => 1162874437075962
                )
            [1] => Array (
                [id] => 806787392777516
                )
            [2] => Array (
                [id] => 929038240485406
                )
            [3] => Array (
                [id] => 825254187600287
                )
            [4] => Array (
                [id] => 10207351162810478
                )
            [5] => Array (
                [id] => 1188696951158141
                )
            )
        [paging] => Array (
            [cursors] => Array (
                [after] => MTE4ODY5Njk1MTE1ODE0MQ==
                [before] => MTE2Mjg3NDQzNzA3NTk2Mg==
                )
            )
        )
    )
[12] => Array (
    [created_time] => 2013-09-28T13:30:19+0000
    [id] => 730004193797310_374905592640507
    )
[13] => Array (
    [message] => all the best.
    [created_time] => 2013-04-10T12:09:08+0000
    [id] => 730004193797310_301060460025021
    )
[14] => Array (
    [message] => Happy birthday. :
    )
[. god bless created_time] => 2012-09-28T06:50:12+0000
[id] => 730004193797310_211688138962254
)
```

---

The below code does the api call and echo the output

```
$getPostsLikes = $fb->get('/me/posts?fields=message,likes.summary(true)&limit=100');
        $getPostsLikes = $getPostsLikes->getGraphEdge()->asArray();
    print_r($getPostsLikes);
    ?>
    <br />
    <br />

    <?php
        // printing likes data as per requirements
        foreach ($getPostsLikes as $key) {
            if(isset($key['message']))
            {
             $key['message']."---Total Likes:";
            if (isset($key['likes'])) {
                echo sizeof($key['likes']) . '<br>';

            }

            }
        }
```

### The above code gives the output as this

1

6

Comment: there is an unlike button. if you like something with the unlike button, it will become an unlike button. no clue what you are talking about, to be honest.

Comment: Please check the array and you will find out...

Comment: it would help to post your api call. this is a pretty weird solution, there is a summary option for those things.

Answer (score 0):

You get the number 2 because the likes array consists of 2 sub arrays: data and paging. You would need to count the number of elements in the data sub array.

But you don´t need to count on your own, you can easily get a summary, for example: `me/feed?fields=message,likes.limit(1).summary(true)`

If you only want to get the most liked message, just go through all of them with your loop and store the current message/data in a variable if it has more likes than the elements before.

Comment: Actually i am trying to print the most liked message and the number of likes

Comment: while using summary(true) i see total count in the API Explorer but not in the array,do you know why?

Comment: different api call? hard to say without knowing your api call.

Comment: /me/feed?fields=message,likes{name,id}

Comment: i changed the api call in my answer, try that api call. no need to get names/ids for likes if you just want to find out how many likes there are. btw, what´s that even for, if i may ask?

Comment: No luck..:( Still showing the same data apart from name

Comment: then edit your question and post the code where you are using the api call

Comment: I updted the question and added api call

Comment: check your array carefully. i am sure the summary is there and you just missed it. look after the list of likes.

Comment: No i can't find anything that indicates the total count.
Screenshot of the output with api call and result
http://i.imgur.com/3yiORmJ.png